# Problems with my ajax get request in Laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new in this, I'm making a reservation system, I'm trying to make a request using ajax in laravel 5.4, which has to return the reservations that have been made in my system, but I can not make this request work and I do not know why , do not enter the function in the controller, here I left my code in case someone can help me please, thank you very much in advance!

I'm using the fullCalendar API.

In the chrome console show me "ajax failed"

This is my controller

```
public function get_events()
{
    $events = Reserva::select("id", "observacion as title", "hora_inicio as start" , "hora_fin as end")->get()->toArray();

    //dd($events);

    //return response()->json($events);
    return json_encode($events);
}
```

My Route in web.php

```
Route::get('/reservas/get', 'ReservaController@get_events');
```

My view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

  @section('content')
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <div class="contenedor">
        Reservas
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="margen_body">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
        <br>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <br>
          <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  @endsection

  @section('js')
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      "use strict";

      var evt = [];

      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      })

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/reservas/get',
        dataType: "JSON",
        sync: false
      }).done(function(r){
        alert("ajax work!");
        evt = r;
      }).fail(function(){
        console.log("ajax failed")
      });

      console.log(evt);

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay, listDay'
      },
      events: evt
    });

    //Make the dashboard widgets sortable using jQuery UI
    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
      placeholder: "sort-highlight",
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      handle: ".box-header, nav-tabs",
      forcePlaceholderSize: true,
      zIndex: 999999
    });
    $(".connectedSortable .box-header, .connectedSortable .nav-tabs-custom").css("cursor", "move");

  });
  </script>
  @endsection
```

Comment: What do you see if you open your `/reservas/get` endpoint directly in the browser? You could also use your browser's developer console "Network" tab to see the ajax request and the actual response sent from the server. It might help explain the error. Another place to check: Laravel's log files.

Comment: You should use chrome's or safari's built-in developer tools (ctrl+shift+i) to track JS errors and track actual AJAX requests.

Is your code wrapped in document.ready? Is there any erros in javascript console? Also try to output something after success callback line.

Another cause for this could be incorrect mime-type for your response returned by server

Comment: why did you comment this line //return response()->json($events) did you get any error with that line

Answer (score 0):

you have to return json response to ajax request.

```
 $data=json_encode($events);

 return response()->json(['status' => 200,'data' =>data]);
```